# Feedback on a ThrottledInvoker class

Tags: c#, multithreading

State in a Fluxor app can be updated many times per second, with each change triggering a render in Blazor.

I wanted to write a class that would throttle these notifications so they don't occur more than X times per second.

The rules are.

1. All calls far apart enough in time should be executed immediately - this will avoid UI lag.
2. If a second call is made within the throttle window, it should be deferred in time and executed at the start of the next window. This is to ensure the later change in data does appear in the UI, but not too soon.
3. Any calls before the deferred one has been completed should be ignored because the outstanding deferred call will tell the UI to refresh when it is executed.

[image: Marbles diagram]

Here is the source code

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fluxor.UnsupportedClasses;

public sealed class ThrottledInvoker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object SyncRoot = new();
    private readonly Action ThrottledAction;
    private DateTime NextAllowedInvokeUtc;
    private bool HasPendingImmediateInvocation;
    private bool HasPendingDeferredInvocation;
    private bool IsDisposed;
    private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;

    public ThrottledInvoker(Action throttledAction)
    {
        ThrottledAction = throttledAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(throttledAction));
        NextAllowedInvokeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Invoke(byte maximumInvokesPerSecond)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
            return;

        int throttleWindowMS =
            maximumInvokesPerSecond == 0
            ? 0
            : 1000 / maximumInvokesPerSecond;

        if (throttleWindowMS == 0)
        {
            ThrottledAction();
            return;
        }

        bool shouldExecuteImmediately = false;
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            if (HasPendingDeferredInvocation)
                return;

            DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            shouldExecuteImmediately =
                !HasPendingImmediateInvocation
                && nowUtc >= NextAllowedInvokeUtc;

            bool shouldExecuteDeferred =
                !shouldExecuteImmediately
                && !HasPendingDeferredInvocation;

            if (shouldExecuteImmediately)
                HasPendingImmediateInvocation = true;
            else if (shouldExecuteDeferred)
                HasPendingDeferredInvocation = true;
        }

        if (shouldExecuteImmediately)
            Invoke(throttleWindowMS, wasImmediateInvoke: true);
        else
            _ = InvokeDeferredAsync(throttleWindowMS);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) return;
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    private void Invoke(int throttleWindowMS, bool wasImmediateInvoke)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                ThrottledAction();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                NextAllowedInvokeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(throttleWindowMS);

                if (wasImmediateInvoke)
                    HasPendingImmediateInvocation = false;
                else
                    HasPendingDeferredInvocation = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask InvokeDeferredAsync(int throttleWindowMS)
    {
        await WaitUntilAfterAsync(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(throttleWindowMS));
        Invoke(throttleWindowMS: throttleWindowMS, wasImmediateInvoke: false);
    }

    private async ValueTask WaitUntilAfterAsync(DateTime targetTimeUtc)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        do
        {
            int totalMillisecondsToWait = (int)Math.Ceiling((targetTimeUtc - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds);
            if (totalMillisecondsToWait <= 0)
                break;

            if (totalMillisecondsToWait > 1000)
                totalMillisecondsToWait = 1000;

            await Task.Delay(totalMillisecondsToWait, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        while (!CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

And here are the unit tests

```cs
using Fluxor.UnsupportedClasses;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace Fluxor.UnitTests.UnsupportedClassesTests.ThrottledInvokerTests;

public class InvokeTests
{
    private ThrottledInvoker Subject;
    private int InvokeCount;
    private Action ActionToExecute;

    public InvokeTests()
    {
        ActionToExecute = () => Interlocked.Increment(ref InvokeCount);
        Subject = new ThrottledInvoker(() => ActionToExecute());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenNotThrottled_ThenInvokesImmediately()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++)
            Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: 0);

        Assert.Equal(42, InvokeCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenInvokedInsideThrottleWindow_ThenDoesNotInvoke()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++)
            Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: 1);

        Assert.Equal(1, InvokeCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenInvokedInsideThrottleWindow_ThenSecondInvokeIsDeferredUntilEndOfThrottleWindow()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 25;
        const int ThrottleWindowMS = (1000 / AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        const int HalfOfAThrottleWindowMS = ThrottleWindowMS / 2;
        const int ThreeThrottleWindowsMS = (int)(ThrottleWindowMS * 3);

        // First invoke should execute immediately.
        Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        if (InvokeCount != 1)
            Assert.Fail($"Expected first Invoke in new throttle window to execute immediately. Expected 1 Invoke but found {InvokeCount}.");

        // Invoke again within the throttle window, this should defer the 2nd call
        // until the start of the next throttle window.
        await Task.Delay(HalfOfAThrottleWindowMS);
        Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        if (InvokeCount != 1)
            Assert.Fail($"Expected second Invoke within throttle window get deferred until the start of the next window. Expected 1 Invoke but found {InvokeCount}.");

        // Ensure the test has finished
        await Task.Delay(ThreeThrottleWindowsMS);

        if (InvokeCount != 2)
            Assert.Fail($"Expected deferred second Invoke to have executed after the next window has started. Expected 2 Invoke but found {InvokeCount}.");
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenInvokedInsideThrottleWindow_ThenMoreThanTwoInvokesAreDiscarded()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 1;
        const int ThrottleWindowMS = (1000 / AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        const int ThreeThrottleWindowsMS = (int)(ThrottleWindowMS * 3);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        if (InvokeCount != 1)
            Assert.Fail($"Expected first Invoke in new throttle window to execute immediately. Expected 1 Invoke but found {InvokeCount}.");

        await Task.Delay(ThreeThrottleWindowsMS);

        if (InvokeCount != 2)
            Assert.Fail("Deferred Invoke was not executed at start of second window.");

        if (InvokeCount > 2)
            Assert.Fail("Expected additional Invokes to be discarded when a deffered Invoke is waiting to execute.");
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenExecutedByMultipleThreads_ThenOnlyOneThreadAtATimeInvokesTheAction()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 25;
        int concurrentExecutionCount = 0;
        int executionCount = 0;

        // Set up the action to execute
        // This ensures each call is on or outside the MS window
        ActionToExecute = () =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            int newConcurrentExecutionCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref concurrentExecutionCount);
            if (newConcurrentExecutionCount != 1)
                Assert.Fail($"Concurrent execution detected (Expected 1, found {newConcurrentExecutionCount}).");
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref concurrentExecutionCount);
        };

        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(1, 256), async (x, _) =>
        {
            while (executionCount < 42)
            {
                await Task.Yield();
                Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
            }
        });
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenExecutedByMultipleThreads_ThenThrottlesSuccessfully()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 25;
        const int WindowSizeMS = (1000 / AllowedInvokesPerSecond);

        // Allow a large window for the first invoke
        long lastInvokedUtcTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1).Ticks;

        int failCount = 0;
        int totalExecutionCount = 0;
        int smallestFailMS = int.MaxValue;

        object syncRoot = new object();

        // Set up the action to execute
        // This ensures each call is on or outside the MS window
        ActionToExecute = () =>
        {
            long nowUtcTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            int elapsedMS = (int)(Math.Ceiling(TimeSpan.FromTicks(nowUtcTicks - lastInvokedUtcTicks).TotalMilliseconds));

            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                lastInvokedUtcTicks = nowUtcTicks;

                if (elapsedMS < WindowSizeMS)
                {
                    failCount++;
                    if (elapsedMS < smallestFailMS)
                        smallestFailMS = elapsedMS;
                }

                totalExecutionCount++;
            }
        };

        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(1, 256), async (x, _) =>
        {
            while (totalExecutionCount < 10)
            {
                await Task.Yield();
                Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
            }
        });


        if (failCount > 0)
            Assert.Fail(
                $"Failed {failCount} times." +
                $" Smallest elapsed time was {TimeSpan.FromTicks(smallestFailMS).TotalMilliseconds} MS" +
                $" when it should be no less than {WindowSizeMS} MS" +
                $" failed {failCount} times.");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenDisposed_ThenInitialActionDoesNotExecute()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 25;

        (Subject as IDisposable).Dispose();
        Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);

        Assert.Equal(0, InvokeCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenDisposed_ThenAlreadyDeferredActionDoesNotExecute()
    {
        const byte AllowedInvokesPerSecond = 25;
        const int WindowSizeMS = (1000 / AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        const int HalfWindowSizeMS = WindowSizeMS / 2;

        Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);
        Subject.Invoke(maximumInvokesPerSecond: AllowedInvokesPerSecond);

        await Task.Delay(HalfWindowSizeMS);
        (Subject as IDisposable).Dispose();

        await Task.Delay(WindowSizeMS * 2);

        Assert.Equal(1, InvokeCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to my understanding you have implemented a rate gate. It is usually done by utilizing a queue and a timer. [Here is an example](https://github.com/QuantConnect/Lean/blob/8c66e2e7157b94ebce3122ed093c121a72c7c92d/Common/Util/RateGate.cs). Is there any particular reason why do you implemented this rather than using one of the nuget packages: [1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JackLeitch.RateGate), [2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CVV.RateGate)?

Comment: @PeterCsala My code looks like it behaves differently. I want my consumer to instruct my class to invoke and then immediately return. If not within the throttle window then execute immediately. If inside the window then deferr an execution for the start of the next window. If one is already deferred then do nothing. 

The purpose is to have my UI update immediately, but not more often than X times per second.